# Windows 2000 to 2008 R2 crash

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a mess.  Was in the process of promoting a 2008 R2 server to DC on a domain that was run by 2000 server.  I believe most of the replication was completed - users and computers showed/listed on 2008 server, etc.  2000 server crashed hard and lost RAID array entirely.  Thought the 2008 server was good to go, only to find out it must have been in the middle somewhere and now seems to be losing ground.

On the 2008 server, we can no longer look at AD Users and Computers, it says the domain doesn't exist or can't be contacted.  Same for the Sites and Services.  I have seized FSMO roles, but that hasn't seemed to help.  For instance, my PC still sees the crashed DC as the logon server.  In addition, in trying to verify the connected DC on my PC using nltest /dsgetdc and /dclist I receive an error stating no such domain exists.

I have not rebooted the server yet after the seize operations.  I have not performed any metadata cleanup activities yet.

The DNS is fine and appears to be working.  Forward and reverse lookup values are there for the domain, and the domain is listed.

Earlier, I started trying to look up why users logon scripts weren't working.  It appears the SYSVOL and NETLOGON shares are not set up as you can't see them when you view the server from the network.  The SYSVOL folder is there, and it looks like it was in the middle of syncing that folder structure when the old server crashed - but it hadn't gotten to user scripts.  I am not worried about the actual scripts - we can recreate them easily.

Running a dcdiag /test:netlogons appears to get everything right as far as domain, server, etc. but fails with An net use or LSAPolicy operation failed - error 67.

The old DC was just an authentication server.  No file sharing any longer, only the logon scripts.  No print or application services/shares.  Pretty simple straightforward.

My fear is that the domain is now so corrupt that we need to start over again.  I did see one article that stated just to simply flip the setting for SysvolReady and the User/Computer data would be accessible again, however I am hesitant to try that.

Should I start with trying to clean up the meta data from the old server, or will that wipe what little valid data I have?

I'm still digging into even logs, etc. to see if I can find anything else...

Comment: Have you made sure that all of the domain members (including the new DC) are using the new DC for primary DNS? If they're still using the old DC for primary DNS then naturally that isn't going to work.

Comment: Yes - all devices and the DC should now point the 2008 server as primary DNS.  That was one of the first actions after the old server crashed.

Comment: How many DCs you have? Sounds like you have only one after the old crashed? Make sure it's pointing to a valid DNS server. Seize FSMO is not enough, please also do metadata cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

Contacted MS support since I was up against a wall.  They did their magic behind the scenes.  What they told me is that the dcpromo had not completed before the old server went down, so it was kind of hung up half done and the 2008 server was not announcing itself as a DC.

We lost the SYSVOL folder contents, which means the group policies and logon scripts.  We didn't do any file sharing, so that was not lost anyway.  We had the users and computers, fortunately, so overall, could have been much worse.  MS rebuilt what was missing short of what I just mentioned.

They could have restored SYSVOL contents however we did not have that backed up on a usable media.  Probably could have made a complete recovery had I simply copied the SYSVOL folder and contents off the old server before we started the dcpromo on the new server and obviously before the old server crashed.

One note for myself, and anyone else moving forward.  Just because you back things up doesn't mean anything if you can restore data from the media or location where you back things up to.  In our case we used a proprietary piece of software that did not create a bootable media so the server had to be rebuilt before restore could commence.  Since we could not rebuild the server, the backup was useless.

Due to our current situation, the $499 for the support call was well worth it.  The MS rep was very professional and took the time to explain what happened, what we lost, and what we needed to do to move forward.  Rather fix things myself, but nice to know they are there if needed.